# cv::Mat.refcount Missing in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

The following works in OpenCV 2.4.9:

```
cv::Mat TestMat(3,3,CV_32F);
int RefCount = *TestMat.refcount;
```

How do I accomplish the same thing in OpenCV 3.0.0b?

Comment: What are your problems with this code ?

Comment: This code doesn't compile because `cv::Mat` no longer has a member variable `refcount` in OpenCV3.0.0b.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
int RefCount = TestMat.u ? (*TestMat.u->refcount) : 0;
```

The reference counter is hiddent in `UMatData u` field. See https://github.com/jet47/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L455 for `UMatData` declaration.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for.  New working code: `int RefCount = Testmat.u->refcount`.  The `TestMat.u` member is of type `UMatData*`.  Thank you!!